# Show ordered Articles per User

Tags: sql-server

I have the following:

```
customerID | OrderID | OrderPosition | Articlenumber|
-----------+---------+---------------+--------------+
101        | 1       | 1             | 123          |
101        | 1       | 2             | 799          |
102        | 2       | 1             | 111          |
103        | 3       | 1             | 456          |
101        | 4       | 1             | 789          |
103        | 5       | 1             | 444          |
103        | 5       | 2             | 999          |
101        | 6       | 1             | 555          |
101        | 6       | 2             | 777          |
101        | 6       | 3             | 222          |
```

and I want the following (sum up max 4 articles (ordered by orderID (higher first) and OrderPosition (lower first)) per customerID):

```
customerID |articelnumber 1|articelnumber 2|articelnumber 3|articelnumber 4|
-------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
101        |555            |777            |222            | 789           |
102        |111            |NULL           |NULL           |NULL           |
103        |444            |999            |456            |NULL           |
```

Tried it like this this, but this is not working correct:

```
select *
from 
(
select customerid, OrderID , OrderPosition, Articlenumber FROM table
) src
pivot
(
  avg (Articlenumber)
  for OrderPosition in ([articelnumber 1], [articelnumber 2], [articelnumber 3], [articelnumber 4])
) piv
```

Comment: But you didn't sum up articles in your example. You want to show frist 4 articles as columns for each customer?

Comment: right - edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to get to the same results as your expected output, but I managed to get it right eventually:

```
if exists (select 1 from sysobjects where name = 'TempTable')
drop table TempTable;

if exists (select 1 from sysobjects where name = 'TempTable2')
drop table TempTable2;

declare @cols   nvarchar(max)
,       @cols2  nvarchar(max)
,       @sql  nvarchar(max)
,       @loop   int;

create table TempTable (id int primary key identity, CustomerID int, OrderID int, OrderPosition int, ArticleNumber int)

insert into TempTable (CustomerID, OrderID, OrderPosition, ArticleNumber) values (101,1,1,123)
insert into TempTable (CustomerID, OrderID, OrderPosition, ArticleNumber) values (101,1,2,799)
insert into TempTable (CustomerID, OrderID, OrderPosition, ArticleNumber) values (102,2,1,111)
insert into TempTable (CustomerID, OrderID, OrderPosition, ArticleNumber) values (103,3,1,456)
insert into TempTable (CustomerID, OrderID, OrderPosition, ArticleNumber) values (101,4,1,789)
insert into TempTable (CustomerID, OrderID, OrderPosition, ArticleNumber) values (103,5,1,444)
insert into TempTable (CustomerID, OrderID, OrderPosition, ArticleNumber) values (103,5,2,999)
insert into TempTable (CustomerID, OrderID, OrderPosition, ArticleNumber) values (101,6,1,555)
insert into TempTable (CustomerID, OrderID, OrderPosition, ArticleNumber) values (101,6,2,777)
insert into TempTable (CustomerID, OrderID, OrderPosition, ArticleNumber) values (101,6,3,222);

create table TempTable2 (CustomerID int, OrderID int, OrderPosition int, ArticleNumber int, ArticleDesc varchar(100))

select @loop = min(id) from TempTable
while @loop is not null

begin
    set @sql    = ' insert into TempTable2 (CustomerID, OrderID, OrderPosition, ArticleNumber, ArticleDesc)
                    select top 4 CustomerID, OrderID, OrderPosition, ArticleNumber, ''ArticleNumber ''+cast(rank() over (order by orderID desc, OrderPosition)as varchar)
                    from    TempTable where CustomerID = '+cast((select CustomerID from TempTable where id = @loop) as varchar)+
                    'order by orderID desc, OrderPosition'
    exec (@sql)
    select @loop = min(id) from TempTable where id > @loop
end

select
    CustomerID
,   sum(isnull([ArticleNumber 1],0))    [ArticleNumber 1]
,   sum(isnull([ArticleNumber 2],0))    [ArticleNumber 2]
,   sum(isnull([ArticleNumber 3],0))    [ArticleNumber 3]
,   sum(isnull([ArticleNumber 4],0))    [ArticleNumber 4]
from
(
select
CustomerID, OrderID, OrderPosition, ArticleDesc, ArticleNumber
from    TempTable2
group by CustomerID, OrderID, OrderPosition, ArticleDesc, ArticleNumber
)   d
pivot
(sum(ArticleNumber) for ArticleDesc in ([ArticleNumber 1],[ArticleNumber 2],[ArticleNumber 3],[ArticleNumber 4])
)   p
group by CustomerID
```

---

My answer might not be the best as the genius guys answered above, but I still get the same results...

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

Modified Sample Data to meet Your Requirement

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP ')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE  #TEMP 
;WITH CTE(customerID , OrderID , OrderPosition , Articlenumber)
AS
(
SELECT 101,  1 , 1 , 123 UNION ALL         
SELECT 101,  1 , 2 , 799 UNION ALL         
SELECT 102,  2 , 1 , 111 UNION ALL         
SELECT 103,  3 , 1 , 456 UNION ALL         
SELECT 101,  4 , 1 , 789 UNION ALL         
SELECT 103,  5 , 1 , 444 UNION ALL         
SELECT 103,  5 , 2 , 999 UNION ALL         
SELECT 101,  6 , 1 , 555 UNION ALL         
SELECT 101,  6 , 2 , 777 UNION ALL         
SELECT 101,  6 , 3 , 222          
)
SELECT * , SUM(ArticleNumber)OVER(PARTITION BY customerID  ORDER BY customerID ) AS SumOfArticlePerCustomer
INTO #TEMP 
FROM
(
SELECT * ,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY customerID ORDER BY OrderID DESC  ) RNk,
    'ArticleNumber_'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY customerID ORDER BY OrderID DESC ) AS VARCHAR(10))  AS ArticleNumberData
FROM CTE
)DT
WHERE RNk <= 4

SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```

Dynamic Sql ,which is used to get generate the column dynamically and meet the expected result

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max),
        @DynamicColumn nvarchar(max),
        @MaxDynamicColumn nvarchar(max)

SELECT @DynamicColumn = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT', '+QUOTENAME(ArticleNumberData )
FROM #TEMP  FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') 

SELECT @MaxDynamicColumn = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT', '+'MAX('+QUOTENAME(ArticleNumberData )+') AS '+QUOTENAME(ArticleNumberData )+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
FROM #TEMP FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,N'')

SET @Sql='SELECT  CustomerID,'+ @MaxDynamicColumn+',SumOfArticlePerCustomer 
            FROM
            (
            SELECT *
            FROM #TEMP 
            )AS src
            PIVOT 
            (
            MAX(Articlenumber) FOR [ArticleNumberData] IN ('+@DynamicColumn+')
            ) AS Pvt
            GROUP BY customerID,SumOfArticlePerCustomer
            ORDER BY  CustomerID'
EXEC (@Sql)
PRINT @Sql
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're after just four columns and a quick output the same as listed above, you can always just use `ROW_NUMBER`, a CTE, and a few joins:

```
;with TopFour
as
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [customerID] ORDER BY orderID DESC, OrderPosition ASC) as [TheOrder]
    FROM [table]
)
SELECT
    a.[customerID],
    a.[Articlenumber] as [articlenumber 1],
    b.[Articlenumber] as [articlenumber 2],
    c.[Articlenumber] as [articlenumber 3],
    d.[Articlenumber] as [articlenumber 4]
FROM 
    TopFour a
LEFT JOIN 
    TopFour b
ON 
    a.customerID = b.customerID
AND 
    b.TheOrder = 2
LEFT JOIN
    TopFour c
ON 
    a.customerID = c.customerID
AND 
    c.TheOrder = 3
LEFT JOIN 
    TopFour d
ON 
    a.customerID = d.customerID
AND 
    d.TheOrder = 4
WHERE 
    a.TheOrder = 1
```